# Algorithm for finding if there's a "common number"

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Let an array with the size of `n`. We need to write an algorithm which checks if there's a number which appears at least `n/loglogn` times.

I've understood that there's a way doing it in `O(n*logloglogn)` which goes something like this:

1. Find the median using select algorithm and count how many times it appears. if it appears more than `n/loglogn` we return `true`. It takes `O(n)`.
2. Partition the array according the median. It takes `O(n)`
3. Apply the algorithm on both sides of the partition (two `n/2` arrays).
4. If we reached a subarray of size less than `n/loglogn`, stop and return false.

**Questions:**

1. Is this algorithm correct?
2. The recurrence is: `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)` and the base case is `T(n/loglogn) = O(1)`. Now, the largest number of calls in the recurrence-tree is `O(logloglogn)` and since every call is `O(n)` then the time complexity is `O(n*logloglogn)`. Is that correct?

Comment: What about a simple dictionary of values and their occurrence count?

Comment: That's actually an idea. I don't know why it hasn't been offered. That's strange

Comment: @AlonAlon It requires O(n) space, and when dealing with stream processing - that's a bad idea. In all other alternatives - that's probably the best solution. Generally speaking, this problem is known as Frequent Item Mining, and [Karp-Papadimitriou-Shanker](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~samir/498/karp.pdf) suggests a pretty efficient solution for it (For general `Theta`, and you are looking for an element that repeats at least `Theta*n` times).

Comment: Thank you @amit. Could you overview the solution suggested and it's complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested solution works, and the complexity is indeed `O(n/logloglog(n))`.

Let's say a "pass i" is the running of all recursive calls of depth `i`. Note that each pass requires `O(n)` time, since while each call is much less than `O(n)`, there are several calls - and overall, each element is processed once in each "pass".

Now, we need to find the number of passes. This is done by solving the equation:

```
n/log(log(n))  = n / 2^x
<->
n/log(log(n)) * 2^x = n
```

And the idea is each call is dividing the array by half until you get to the predefined size of `n/log(log(n))`.

This problem is indeed solved for x in `O(n/log(log(log(n)))`, as [you can see in wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28n%2Flog%28log%28n%29%29%29%20*%202%5Ex%20%3D%20n), and thus the complexity is indeed `O(nlog(log(log(n))))`

As for correctness - that's because if an element repeats more than the required - it must be in some subarray with size greater/equals the required size, and by reducing constantly the size of the array, you will arrive to a case at some point where `#repeats <= size(array) <= #repeats` - at this point, you are going to find this element as the median, and find out it's indeed a "frequent item".

Some other approach, in `O(n/log(log(n))` time - but with great constants is suggested by [Karp-Papadimitriou-Shanker](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~samir/498/karp.pdf), and is based on filling a table with "candidates" while processing the array.

Comment: Thank you so much Amit. I appreciate very much your efforts to help me!